# check if script ran successfully?

Tags: python, return-value

I have code that runs commands in bash (each bash command runs a function python script), I wish to check if the script ran successfully or not, as in was there any error. Here is the code:

```
    for command in command_list:
        if subprocess_cmd(command):
            print "success"
        else:
            print "fail"

def subprocess_cmd(command):
    process = subprocess.Popen(command.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    proc_stdout = process.communicate()[0].strip()
```

this always prints fail, even though everything runs fine, is what I am doing making sense?
How do I do this?

Edit: answer is the returncode attribute of popen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your function `subprocess_cmm` is not returning anything, so by default `None` is returned which is a **Falsy** value.

Default return value of a function is always `None`.

```
>>> def func():
...     pass
>>> print func()
None
```

**Update:**

```
import shlex
for command in command_list:
   try:
       out = subprocess.check_output(shlex.split(command))
       print out
   except CalledProcessError:
       print "fail"
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I test the return value of the python script that the bash command is calling?

Comment: @Paul if you only want the output, then use `subprocess.check_output`.

Comment: I just want to check if it was a success or not, basically if it was 0 or not. I'll have a look at the subprocess command thanks, now that I know what to do.

Comment: @Paul use `subprocess.call`, it returns a 0 or non-zero value depending whether the call worked or not.

Comment: I see that now thanks, however will that just return success if the bash command was ran sucessfully, or will it actually return the return value of the command it ran, a python script in the case?Also that seems to return the output of the command as well as the 0

Comment: @Paul use `ret = subprocess.call(....)`, if `ret` is 0 then return `True` else return `False`. There's also `subprocess.check_call`, instead of returning a non-zero value it raises an error when a command fails.
`

Comment: if i do that call command then my communicate line fails, so im working on it yet :)

Comment: @Paul remove that function, and replace that `if` condition with :`if not subprocess_call(...):`

Comment: I think the answer here is to actually use the popen command still, so that i get the data as well as the exit code. i can then use the returncode attribute of popen, which is what i was missing

Comment: my answer works but will accept yours for the help and thought process, thanks.

Comment: @Paul also check my updated solution, note that you should use `shlex.split` for splitting.

Comment: why do I need to use shlex instead? why I didnt use call or check_call is that an int was being returned and communicate was failing.

Comment: @Paul Because you're using `str.split` here, which is not suitable for shell commands, see the difference : http://ideone.com/aNIEZt

Comment: This does not work for me, if the cmd fails, it still returns within `try`. Never gets to the `except`